# Person component on Peoplesoft CRM 8.90.00.000 has a save issue after tools upgrade 8.52

Tags: peoplesoft

I know this is a long shot but I am trying to find someone who had dealt with the same kind of problem. Person component on our PS Application ( CRM 8.90.00.000 ) is not saving any data changes on the component except level 0 (Which is RD_PERSON). This is happening after the tools upgrade to 8.52. We do not have Application support from oracle.

If you have faced this kind of issue before, please let me know what caused it and how it was fixed.

Thank You.

Comment: you should contact their support.

Comment: Please put Forum post on My Oracle Support Community https://community.oracle.com/community/support/

Answer (score 0):

Try a SQL trace as a starting point and see if there are any rollbacks occurring in that SQL trace which may be causing the component to save to a certain point, hit an error and rollback changes. Perhaps a table doesn't exist or it doesn't match the record definition in App Designer.

Also have you run the relevant post-upgrade/install reports to look for any issues? E.g. DDDAUDIT and SYSAUDIT? Check the upgrade manual for how to do that.

Try running an alter audit too if you suspect there may be tables in the database that do not match their record definitions: http://peoplesoft.wikidot.com/alter-audit